# Dynamically add an iFrame in a Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am very new to AngularJs and I have created a pretty nifty Modal factory. What I am trying to accompish and cannot figure it out is in the "text" for the modal inject and iFrame so I can display other HTML pages. I want to be able to just call my factory and then just specify the URL and the factory will do the work. I have created a Plunker to show what I have, and my attempts at injecting the iFrame

http://plnkr.co/edit/KGz4rWXlxfbJmyzBBwyP?p=preview

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">{{alert_data.title}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>{{alert_data.text}}</h3>
           <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"width="100%" height="100%"frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: So mine will launch an iFrame as shown in my Demo, but I manually added that into my Modal Template, I want tho be able to add the specific URL in the AngularJs Controller and inject it into the template

Comment: use a data binding on the `<iframe src="{{alert_data.iframeSrc}}" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already passing scope to the modal in the 'alert_data' object, so just tack on the URL to it, expose it in the service as a parameter and bind it to the iframe src.

```
function alert(type, text, size, url) {
    var template = type === 'success' ? 'template-success.html' : 'template-error.html';

    var opts = {
        size : size || 'sm'
    };
    var data = {
        title : type === 'success' ? "OK" : "Ooops",
        text :  function(){return text},
        url: url
    };

    return openModal(template, data, opts);
}
```

And then in the template:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ alert_data.url }}" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

You may also have to use the $sce service to trust the URL.

```
var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Here's an updated Plunkr as an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/d1OLRdhc6vKr6OZa6GkN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could use use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/bJpu7NfHE4mtVgBEqKKy?p=preview).

Note that you need to set your `src` as trusted by calling  `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()` (see [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) for more information as to why it's needed). Line 27 and following:

```
controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $sce, alert_data) {
      $scope.alert_data = alert_data;
      $scope.iframeSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

js paste iframe:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/test");
        iframe.setAttribute("width", "100%");
        iframe.setAttribute("height", "315");
        iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
        document.getElementById("wrapper_video").appendChild(iframe);
```

for paste in html you need to inject $sce

```
return $sce.trustAsHtml(iframe);
```